# How can I prevent Bootstrap panels from getting larger than browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a node.js application.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Chat</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul id="messages"></ul>
          <form id="chat">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send">Send</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="list-group" id="users"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

As chat messages and users get added to each panel, both panels grow down beyond what the browser can see unless the user scrolls.

I want both panels to start as 100% height of the browser and to not grow past the browser size, so no scrolling on the browser, but I want the user to be able to scroll within each panels themselves!

**Update**

Using the below CSS as suggested in an answer still shows a scroll bar on the window, also how to I get the form to be fixed to the bottom of the chat panel and the scrolling to happen above it?

```
.panel {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-body {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: M.M.M.M.M.Max Height might be able to help you.

Comment: I tried setting them both to `height:100%` but that didn't have any effect. No idea how to stop the scrolling, hence the question.

Comment: You haven't made it clear what element should scroll.

Comment: Sorry. I want the messages to scroll in the chat panel, and the list items (users) to scroll in the users panel.